# Unable to deploy react app to gitlab pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gitlab

I'm running into a problem I can't quite figure out... I am trying to deploy a react app to gitlab pages, but i keep getting an error

here are my scripts in the

```
image: node:12.16.0


variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: /test

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules


stages:
- deploy


pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build --prod
    - cp public/index.html public/404.html 
    - mv public _public 
    - mv build public 
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public 
  only:
    - master
```

The error is this

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! fantastico@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 build script.
```

The rest is pretty straight forward. I push a react app to gitlab, and added these scripts to hopefully make it a page... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a more explicit stack trace?

Comment: I have a error log here.

/root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-28T09_17_32_564Z-debug.log

however... not sure how to access it given that I can't get to it through bash

Comment: The build pass localy?

Comment: Yeah. Everything works locally.

Comment: Could you also print your package.json?